# Laplace equation on the 3-sphere

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, harmonic-functions

In the article [The Ellipse and the Atom](https://www.gregegan.net/SCIENCE/Ellipse/Ellipse.html#FMS), the author mentions, but does not precisely prove, that the equation

$$\Psi(\mathbf{s}) - \frac{m}{2s^2} \frac{k}{2 \pi^2 \hbar} \int_{s S^3} \frac{\Psi(\mathbf{s'})}{|\mathbf{s}-\mathbf{s'}|^2} d\Omega' = 0$$

on the 3-sphere $s S^3$ of radius $s > 0$ is equivalent to the Laplace equation on the sphere. Where can I find a more thorough discussion of that equivalence?